# How to make ajax call on clicking a button and process server side code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a button named Finish Payment in my page:

```
<button style="background-color:#73bd5a; color:#FFF;" id="finish_payment" name="finish_payment" type="button" class="btn btn-white active pull-right">
        <i class="ion-checkmark-circled"></i></i> Finish Payment
</button>
```

What I want to do is when I click this button I want to update the payment status "Unpaid" to "Paid" in table client_payment and after updating change the button text to paid without refreshing the page. The ajax code I have used is given below:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function( ) {
        $( document ).on( 'click', '#finish_payment', function( ) {
            $.ajax( {
                url: "update_payment.php?id=<?php echo $client_id; ?>";
                        success: function( response ) {
                            $( "#finish_payment" ).html( 'Paid' );
                        }
            } );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

And the server side code I have is:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bn");
$client_id  = $_GET['id'];
$query      = "UPDATE client_payment
                SET payment_status='true'
                WHERE client_id = $client_id";
if( mysqli_query($connection, $query) )
{
    echo"Payment Complete";
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Your logic seems fine, do you have an issue? It should be noted however, that your PHP code is ***wide*** open to SQL injection attacks. I'd suggest you change the code to use prepared statements ASAP

Comment: Your callback attempts to update the HTML of your button with the value 'Paid' You want to use `val('Paid')` instead of `html('Paid')` to update the button text